# VisitClassDeclaration node.Identifier in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

How can I find what line number in the source file the declaration was found on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

You can use the `ISyntaxTree.GetLineSpan()` method to convert to a line number.  For example, given an `ISymbol` "symbol", you can get the start location of the first definition with:

```
var loc = symbol.Locations.First();
var lineSpan = loc.SourceTree.GetLineSpan(loc.SourceSpan, 
    usePreprocessorDirectives: false);
var line = lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Line;
var character = lineSpan.StartLinePosition.Character;
```

From the title, it looks like you're starting with a `SyntaxNode`, so you can just use the `Span` property directly.

Comment: I know it's a long-tail project, but is there a link to the documentation online?

Comment: We don't have the documentation in the MSDN format yet.  The closest we have at the moment are the various documents up at  http://msdn.com/roslyn

Comment: I don't see the StartLinePosition here

`public class MyVisitor : SyntaxRewriter
{

    protected override SyntaxNode VisitClassDeclaration(ClassDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Identifier.ValueText);
        return null;
    }
}`

Comment: Excellent, it worked `tree.GetLineSpan(node.Identifier.Span, false).StartLinePosition.Line`